# Replacing old fixtures, double wiring

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

I am replacing old fixtures with LED's in a 1994 mobile home. In taking an old fixture down I find 2 black, 2 white and 1 ground.

The new LED has only one of each. There are 3 lights on one line. I wired the LED up as indicated by old wiring and the LED will not work. I put  the old fixture back up and it works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this fixture on a dimmer, or just a plain lightswitch?

Comment: No dimmer. Just one plain switch for all three lights. Entertaining the idea that maybe the new fixture is bad? Thank you for responding so quickly.

Comment: Check he fixture. Seems it may be problem. Wiring iss OK.

Comment: Try a different fixture. While not likely, it is possible that you got a bad one in the box.

Comment: @KH you can simply delete your comment if it's no longer applicable. Right there next to the `edit` link.

Comment: @Aimy please remove your edit and paste it into the Answer box below. As noted in the [tour] this is a Question & _Answer_ site, thus answers are expected and without them, the site can be confusing. Self answers are most welcome, and you'll likely get a vote or two for it. You can also click the check-mark next to your answer so others will know that this has a resolution - that will help them find it.

Comment: The whites are taped black in the picture, indicating a switchoop.   Did you attach white to white, black to black?   Or  white to black and black to white?   Leds might be sensitive to correct wiring that normal lamps aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your comments. It was the new fixture. I bought 10 of them and the first one I installed was a dud. Naturally, I thought I did something wrong. Thanks again!